MongoDB page size fine tuning disabling the compression
We are having partitioned collections. Due to AWS disk limitations we have set the allocation_size to 64KB, internal_page_max to 64KB and leaf_page_max to 64KB
The IOPS decreased dramatically however we noticed increase in storage ( 4X ). Collection r_09_2024 is with default parameters ( allocation_size - 4KB, internal_page_max - 4KB and leaf_page_max - 32KB )
Collection: r_09_2024 - Size: 1.23 TB, Storage Size: 412.03 GB
Collection: r_10_2024 - Size: 1.43 TB, Storage Size: 1.71 TB
Collection: r_11_2024 - Size: 1.13 TB, Storage Size: 1.18 TB
What should we do to allow compression with bigger block size?

Do you think this is a sustainable way to run your application? In a few month you will hit the limitation again. Upgrade your MongoDB to next level or consider to run it locally if you are not willing to pay for it.

@WernfriedDomscheit the cpu is hardly at 35% , memory is less then 50. we have plenty of resources and 4 shards in overall. We do plan to grow by adding more shards , but since we have the botlleneck strictly on the disks we want to optimize the usage.

I guess you use Mongo Atlas. Do you need the data on a "hot" storage? If not, then consider Atlas Online Archive

Check collStats output for "bytes available for reuse" to see if any of those collections have significant empty space in the file.

I have found the root cause. When i set allocation_size and internal_page_max to 16KB , the compression is working fine. When i set it to 64KB it does not works.... So it looks like we cant set the blocks > then max IOPS , otherwise it will just not work
